# Producer - Consumer implementation with semaphores

Tags: java, concurrency

Let's suppose that I have the following:

- Producers P1, P2.
- Consumers C1, C2.

C1 should take items that P1 put into the buffer, and C2 should take items that P2 put into the buffer.

What could happen if C1 or C2 access to the buffer but there's no items that they can consume?

For example, C1 gets access to the buffer but there's no elements produced by P1 in the buffer,  could it lead to a livelock?

Comment: If there are deadlocks or livelocks or other concurrency issues depends on a particular implementation. Show yours if you want us to review it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to design `Consumer` and `Producer` as `Thread` and use a data-structure for their operations with `synchronized` for blocking. You should look over `Thread` class and how to work with `wait-notify`.

```
class DS extends ArrayList<String>
{
   public void synchronized addItem(String item)
   {
       this.add(item);
       notify();
   }
   public String synchronized getItem()
   {
       while(this.size()==0)
       {
            try
            {
              wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { }; 
       }
       String out = this.get(0);
       this.remove(0)
       return out;
   }
}
...
class Producer extends Thread {
DS ds;
public Producer(DS ds)
{
    this.ds = ds;
}
...
     public void run()
     { 
        while(true)
        {
              try {Thread.sleep((long) (1000*Math.random()));}
              catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
              String products[] = {"A", "B" ,"C" , "D" };
              int select = (int)((products.length)*Math.random());
              ds.addItem(products[select]);
              System.out.println("add product:"+products[select]);
        }
     }
...
}
class Consumer extends Thread { ... 
//similar with Producer but this time will get a product on run()
}

class Main
{
    DS ds = new DS();
    Consumer c = new Consumer(ds);
    Producer p = new Producer(ds);
    c.start();
    p.start();
}
```